# Does Salesforce Touch support an offline mode or if not are there plans for it to do so?

Tags: mobile, editions

I have a question about the Salesforce Touch, I know that is not yet released but the video described in www.salesforce.com/touch/ site it says that we can work offline, I was very happy for this feature, because here in Brazil in some places farthest not have internet access, for example: a farm in the Amazon.
In some materials provided by Salesforce.com I read that *"Salesforce Touch does not support offline working."* Someone can tell me if it is only in this and the next will be deployed this functionality? If not, here I leave a suggestion for an app that becomes very complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official documentation offline use is not *currently* supported.  I would be surprised if it wasn't on the roadmap, though.

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000044637&language=en_US

> **Where can I learn how to use Salesforce Touch?**
>
> **Knowledge Article Number: 000044637**
>
> **Description**
>
> The Salesforce Touch FAQ is the official documentation for Salesforce Touch and provides information about using the app, as well >as answers to common questions.
>
> You can access the FAQ directly from the app by selecting the Settings icon (located in the upper right corner of the app and looks like a gear).

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/touch_faq_tablet/index.htm

> **Overview** | **What are the requirements for using Salesforce Touch?**
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> **Wireless Connection:**
>
> A Wi-Fi® or cellular network connection is required to communicate with Salesforce. For the best performance, we recommend using Wi-Fi. If you use Salesforce Touch on a 3G cellular network, data rates may apply and you may incur roaming charges while traveling.
>
> Offline use of Salesforce Touch isn’t currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

Although I, too, wouldn't be surprised if Salesforce provides more "official" support for offline mode in the future, my recommendation is that you're still probably going to be better off building your own offline app framework or finding a third party app that meets your needs.

Offline apps have *wildly* differing requirements around when/how/what to sync, how to store locally, how to handle versioning & merging of edit conflicts, and the end-user workflows around those activities. Even in the mid-term I think you'll find that constructing these yourself will result in the most solid app experience.